# How to use/remap Azure KeyVault secret as Azure DevOps Pipeline environment variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I'm storing database connection string in Azure KeyVault and would like to use / remap keyvault secret `DB-DEV-CONNECTION-STRING` to `ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__ConnectionString` environment variable so my server can read it as configuration property during startup.

I'm using web configuration (not YAML) and don't know how to reference variable so that it is not called `DB-DEV-CONNECTION-STRING` but `ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__ConnectionString`.
I have linked keyvault in my piplene and secret is succesfuly downloaded when build job starts.

I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: This can be accomplished via your ARM template. Look at referencing keyvault secrets within an ARM template. There is no need to involve your release pipeline.

Comment: Can you point some example of this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a PowerShell task after the key vault task and set the variable:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings_ConnectionString]$(DB-DEV-CONNECTION-STRING)"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I will test it later and let you know.

Comment: This approach works, I have used cmd with echo. Quotes should be ommited.
So command goes like this:
`echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__ConnectionString;]$(DB-DEV-CONNECTION-STRING)`

Two underscores represent sub property in web.config, its same as:  `ConnectionStrings.ConnectionString`